# PHP variable as input value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to make a voting system. The form below is located in an **echo**. So I want the  $entree_id to be filled in as the value of the hidden field and stored in a database when someone clicks on the submit button. But whenever I try it, the row stays empty.

This is the database output:

`$entree_id     = $row['entree_id'];`

And this is in the echo:

`<form action='/' method='post'><input type='hidden' name='entree_id' value='" . $entree_id . "'><input type='submit' class='button'></form><p>`

I have also tried something like this:

`<form action='/' method='post'><input type='hidden' name='entree_id' value='<?php print $entree_id ?>'><input type='submit' class='button'></form><p>`

Why don't I get the value of $entree_id?

Comment: test your generated html and post that here too

Comment: you probably don't get a value because either you don't insert the value in the database the right way or you don't retrieve the value the right way.

Comment: Code missing, how is generated `$row` variable? We need that code to tell you what's happening.

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean by that? Do you mean something like this: $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM entree");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))

Comment: print_r($row); Put that in that while loop and tell us what it outputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must distinguish between html and php. your variables should be betwen php tags.
try this

```
    <form action='' method='post'><input type='hidden' name='entree_id' value='<?php echo $entree_id ; ?>' /><input type='submit' class='button' /></form><p>
```

EDIT:

inside the echo then it will be like this

```
     echo "<form action='' method='post'>
 <input type='hidden' name='entree_id' value='".$entree_id."' />
 <input type='submit' class='button' />
 </form>" ;
```

make sure that type is hidden .

change it to

```
    type='text'  //or what ever to see the value.
```

Comment: his code is good, his problem is that value of $entree_id isn't what he expected (it's empty)

Comment: No, it didn't work. Can the fault be somewhere else in my code? Maybe I was on the wrong track?

Comment: if he echo `$entree_id` by it self and if there is value then this form should work or its his problem from getting this variable

Comment: @bloopp-it What I don't get is, where is the value coming in from? Your field is set to `hidden`, therefore it needs a preset value set for it, if it is to remain hidden.

Comment: The id comes from another table.

Comment: @bloopp-it Then your problem is most likely to be in there. Check and re-check your syntax.

Comment: Ah just post the rest of your code like the other guys suggested.

Comment: @bloopp-it you sure that you make the hidden field `type='hidden'` ? change it to `type='text'` and see if there is value

Comment: After the database connection, I have this: $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM entree"); while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { $entree_id = $row['entree_id']; echo "<form action='voteform.php' method='post'><input type='hidden' name='entree_id' value='".$entree_id."'><input type='submit' class='button'></form><p>"; } mysqli_close($con); ?>

Comment: @echo_Me Yes, I have some values (like 1, 2...)

Comment: look my comment and my updated answer , maybe you are making the field hidden , try make it text

Comment: Put (print_r($row);) in that row and tell us what it outputs

Comment: Put `or trigger_error($link->error."[ $result]");` after your query and say if there is error

Comment: `print_r($row);` did you tried to put that in your while loop?

Comment: post your table also please.

Comment: Good news! I've finally found it! In my form there was a '$' that didn't belong there... I want to thank everybody for your great effort and help. I was on the wrong track for which I apologize very much.

Comment: that would tell us anything. if it is an int then it will display a number. and he said it has a value

Comment: Is there any way to reward you for all the effort because I feel sorry about it?

Comment: well you have 6 reputation so I don't think you can upvote. maybe when you get 15 reputation you can upvote some of the posts...

Comment: Oh, okay, I will keep that in mind for the future when I get there!

Comment: @bloopp-it I'm glad you found your problem, however next time, post your entire codes, it'll save us all (including you) a lot of time, while **leaving the guesswork out** of it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Both of those SHOULD work if there is already a value in $entree_id at the time PHP is running.  If you do the first one you were talking about...

```
<form action='/' method='post'><input type='hidden' name='entree_id' value='" . $entree_id . "'><input type='submit' class='button'></form><p>
```

... then you will need it to be part of an echo statement (which it sounds like you might already be doing):

```
<?php
$entree_id = 5;
echo "<form action='/' method='post'><input type='hidden' name='entree_id' value='" . $entree_id . "'><input type='submit' class='button'></form><p>";
?>
```

(Don't forget the semicolon at the end!)  This produced output for me like this:

```
<form action='/' method='post'><input type='hidden' name='entree_id' value='5'><input type='submit' class='button'></form><p>
```

But you could also do it the 2nd way you were saying, I think this might be more readable.  You don't have to use an echo statement for the whole thing, just for the variable:

```
<?php 
    $entree_id = 5; 
?> 
<form action='/' method='post'><input type='hidden' name='entree_id' value='<?php echo $entree_id; ?>'><input type='submit' class='button'></form><p>
```

Notice I changed your "print" to an "echo" and I also added a semicolon at the end of the echo.

This worked for me too, producing this output:

```
<form action='/' method='post'><input type='hidden' name='entree_id' value='5'><input type='submit' class='button'></form><p>
```

Hope this helps!  Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: I just want to say that this code does the same thing as his.

Comment: I think bloopp-it's main issue might be that he's not getting his expected $entree_id value from the database.  Maybe if he posts the database query and php code it will help.

Comment: Does it matter the entree_id is an integer?

Comment: That code is ok. And no, if it is integer it is converted to string

Answer (score 0):

Change your echo to use single quotes, instead of double quotes, like so:

```
echo '
<form action="/" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="entree_id" value="' . $entree_id . '"><input type="submit" class="button"></form>';
```

double quotes can be used in php for outputting variables automatically.  Using Single quotes makes this less confusing and ensures that the `.` is concenating to it properly.